# What is the difference between "embrulhar", "empacotar", and "agasalhar"?

Tags: verbos

I have learned that all three words "embrulhar", "empacotar", and "agasalhar" correspond to the english word "to pack". However, I would like to know which one is the most common to use and whether there are differences in the meaning.

Comment: "agasalhar" don't have the meaning of to pack...

Comment: Agasalhar means... to wrap, to make snug. Mothers would tell their children to "agasalhar-se" during cold or rainy days. (In slang, "agasalhar" could also mean to steal, in the sense of "to protect something inside one's clothes" [e.g. jacket].)

Comment: Sky Passaro, `the most common to use`... in which situation?

Comment: In English it makes no sense to use "to pack" for wearing warm clothes. You can "pack" clothes in your luggage, but that's it. This translation is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Empacotar = to pack

It can be used for packing something in a box, in a bag, etc. It's used for things that require a certain degree of protection (using cardboard, for example).

> "Vou empacotar o produto e enviar para o cliente."

## Embrulhar = to wrap

For things that don't need too much protection (using paper, for example). It can be used in the context of wrapping a present.

> "Vou embrulhar os presentes de Natal".

## Agasalhar = to put warm clothes on

Your translation of this last one is wrong, agasalhar is not to pack. Google Translate is currently showing this translation, but that is wrong.

Comment: Actually, "to pack" can be translated to "agasalhar", but only in a very unusual sense used in medicine. See http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pack. Unless specifically in this context, you won't use it.

Comment: "embrulhar" and "empacotar" can be considered synonyms in many (most?) cases. For example, in Brazil, the desk where you pack a present in stores is often called "setor de pacotes".